# Dependency error with mfc140.dll despite it being present in the System32 folder

Tags: dependencies, visual-studio-2019

In our product, there is a dll A that loads another dll B which has dependency on mfc140.dll. The mfc140.dll is present in the System32 folder. But the dll A is not able to load the dll B due to dependency error with the mfc dll.

Placed mfc140.dll in the folder where dll A is present but the problem did not get solved. When checked the dll B in dependency walker it reported error with mfc140.dll.

Any assistance on this will be a great favour.